# Making bar chart adjust to data passed in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am fighting to make this bar chart automatic. It should display properly after I pass in 6, 8 or 15 elements in the array. It works properly for 16 elements + 1. The first is an empty element ( which is a bit annoying as well). 
This is the barchart: http://bl.ocks.org/kiranml1/6872226

I dont really know what I should change to make it work. Spent few good hours already..(d3 newbie)

I cut down some of the stuff, like grid and x- axis ( I dont need it ).

Here is my code (same as example on website, except some functionality)

```
        var categories = ['', 'Accessories', 'Audiophile', 'Camera & Photo', 'Cell Phones', 'Computers', 'eBook Readers', 'Gadgets', 'GPS & Navigation'];

            var dollars = [213, 209, 190, 179, 156, 209, 190, 179];

            var colors = ['#0000b4', '#0082ca', '#0094ff', '#0d4bcf', '#0066AE', '#074285', '#00187B', '#285964', '#405F83', '#416545', '#4D7069', '#6E9985', '#7EBC89', '#0283AF', '#79BCBF', '#99C19E'];



            var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([10, 260])
                .range([0, 622]);

            var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, categories.length])
                .range([0, 480]);

            var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
                .domain([0, categories.length])
                .range(colors);

            var canvas = d3.select('#twoDbInfo')
                .append('svg')
                .attr({
                    'width': 900,
                    'height': 550
                });



            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis();
            yAxis
                .orient('left')
                .scale(yscale)
                .tickSize(2)
                .tickFormat(function (d, i) {
                    return categories[i];
                })
                .tickValues(d3.range(17));

            var y_xis = canvas.append('g')
                .attr("transform", "translate(150,0)")
                .attr('id', 'yaxis')
                .call(yAxis)
                .style("fill", "White");


            var chart = canvas.append('g')
                .attr("transform", "translate(150,0)")
                .attr('id', 'bars')
                .selectAll('rect')
                .data(dollars)
                .enter()
                .append('rect')
                .attr('height', 19)
                .attr({
                    'x': 0,
                    'y': function (d, i) {
                        return yscale(i) + 19;
                    }
                })
                .style('fill', function (d, i) {
                    return colorScale(i);
                })
                .attr('width', function (d) {
                    return 0;
                });


            var transit = d3.select("svg").selectAll("rect")
                .data(dollars)
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("width", function (d) {
                    return xscale(d);
                });

            var transitext = d3.select('#bars')
                .selectAll('text')
                .data(dollars)
                .enter()
                .append('text')
                .attr({
                    'x': function (d) {
                        return xscale(d) - 200;
                    },
                    'y': function (d, i) {
                        return yscale(i) + 35;
                    }
                })
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d + "$";
                }).style({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'font-size': '14px'
                });
```

Comment: When the number of array elements passed in is smaller than in the example, labels are not alligned with the bars. I want barchart to be dynamic(aligns properly depending on data)

Comment: You are using the categories as data source for yAxis, but you draw rects based on dollars. Why don't you combine the datas into one json array? You mean passed in smaller array elements is what? (dollars? categories?) I guess you pass smaller dollars cause the issue?

Comment: I have put your code into a plnkr, please update it to show the incorrect behavior:http://plnkr.co/edit/Lg9UZdhHTrSTr1wXUDhw?p=preview

Comment: Here is plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/tQRUEEokxwQdyj9Q24zI?p=preview
You can see the categories labels are not aligned with the bars. I need it to be always as in first example whether I pass 10 elements or 20.

Answer (score 0):

I update a little bit on the plnkr, add margin and padding, comment part of code unrelated to the question(grid and bars transition, you can add it back easily):

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dVoM4zyPa2qJhUDw8MFY?p=preview)

The most important thing to you question, I think you should use ordinal scale for yAxis instead of linear scale:

```
var yscale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(categories)
        .rangeBands([0, height], .1);
```

Comment: Seems better. Would be good to have a fixed size bar(height-eg. 30px each always), but I guess this could be fixed with the canvas height. I will look closer at the code when I get home. Will try to get the transition and dollar text back on.

Comment: Yeah works nice. Got the transition to work. Can you show me where to put the label back(dollar value) on the chart? Uncommenting the previous code doesnt bring it back.

Comment: Sorry for late reponse, I just come back from weekends:). Please see the updated plnkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/Z1peiErpGbuoNmau87w8?p=preview